# Print image with Chrome using command line switches / startup arguments

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, printing, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

Is there a way to open an image url with Chrome and print that image on start up using command line switches (start up arguments).

It can be headless or non headless. Printing to the default printer is fine as well.

[This appears to be a complete list of chrome command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but I'm not seeing anything that does quite what I'd like it to, although there's around 1,300 options so I may be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a goofy work around that works for my specific situation. I am using C#, so this answer is C# specific, although you could probably apply the idea to most languages.

I start up chrome in `--kiosk, --kiosk-printing` mode, which disables print dialog. I then wait for chrome to start up. I then send the  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> keys. The full method looks like this.

```
public void printImageUrlWithChrome(string url)
{
    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        // Start Chrome in kiosk with kiosk printing (no printing confirmation window)
        process.StartInfo.FileName = Properties.Settings.Default.googleChrome;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + " --kiosk --kiosk-printing";
        process.Start();

        // Wait for Kiosk to load
        int millisecondWaitForChrome = 1000;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(millisecondWaitForChrome)

        // Send CTRL + p
        SendKeys.Send("^(p)");
    }
}
```

Would still prefer a less goofy solution, preferably something with command switches only.

Comment: Good idea! I will try it in Python. How do you exit --kiosk mode?

Comment: @HrvojeT Ctrl  + W will close the window. You can't convert a kiosk mode window to normal mode as far as I know.

Comment: Np, I will kill Chrome after printing

Comment: If I have Chrome opened before it won't go in kioks mode in WinXP. So I simulate press ctrl-p and then enter with
import win32com.client
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{ENTER}", 0)